# How to register without email verification?

Tags: php

I am using a digital product download website with PayPal payment gateway.
This site enables registration by sending an email verification link.
Sometimes email is not delivered to user's inbox, sometimes it gets delayed and everytime it goes to spam folder.

I want to change this setting via PHP file. And user can register site without verifying email.

User will able to login after register without any verification.

I have a code:

```
// Login page
public function login($key='')
{
    if( $this->ts_functions->getsettings('loginhome','checkbox') == '0' ) {
        redirect(base_url());
    }
    if($key != '') {
        $res = $this->DatabaseModel->access_database('ts_user','select','',array('user_key'=>$key,'user_status'=>2));
        if( !empty($res) ) {
            $data['invalidAccess'] = 1;
            $this->DatabaseModel->access_database('ts_user','update',array('user_status'=>1,'user_key'=>''),array('user_key'=>$key));
        }
        else {
            $data['invalidAccess'] = 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        $data['invalidAccess'] = 2;
    }
    $data['basepath'] = base_url();
    $data['name_of_page'] = 'login';

    $this->load->view('themes/'.$this->theme.'/home/authenticate/common_header',$data);
    $this->load->view('themes/'.$this->theme.'/home/authenticate/login',$data);
    $this->load->view('themes/'.$this->theme.'/home/authenticate/common_footer',$data);
}

// Register page
public function register()
{
    if( $this->ts_functions->getsettings('registerhome','checkbox') == '0' ) {
        redirect(base_url());
    }

    $data['basepath'] = base_url();
    $data['name_of_page'] = 'register';
    $this->load->view('themes/'.$this->theme.'/home/authenticate/common_header',$data);
    $this->load->view('themes/'.$this->theme.'/home/authenticate/register',$data);
    $this->load->view('themes/'.$this->theme.'/home/authenticate/common_footer',$data);
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP Mailer to send emails

Visit: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial

for more info or update your code to stop checking if the user email is verified.